# Retaining trait individualities while mixing them in

Tags: scala, design-patterns, traits

I want to create an enity system with some special properties, based on Scala traits.

The main idea is this: all components are traits that inherit from the common trait:

```
trait Component
trait ComponentA extends Component
```

sometimes, in case of a more complex hierarchy and inter-dependant components it can get like this:

```
trait ComponentN extends ComponentM {
  self: ComponentX with ComponentY =>

  var a = 1
  var b = "hello"
}
```

and so on. I have come to the conclusion that the data relevant to each component should be contained in itself and not in some storage inside an `Entity` or elsewhere because of the speed of the access. As a side note - that is also why everything is mutable, so there is no need in thinking about immutability.

Then `Entities` are created, mixing in the traits:

```
class Entity

class EntityANXY extends ComponentA
  with ComponentN
  with ComponentX
  with ComponentY
```

Here all is fine, however I do have a special requirement that I do not know how to fulfill with the code. The requirement is this:

Each trait must provide an encoding  method(?) that facilitates collection of the trait-related data in a universal form, for example in a form of a JSON or a `Map` like `Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> "hello")` and a decoding method to translate such a map, if received, back into the trait-related variables. Also: 1) all the encoding and decoding methods of all the mixed-in traits are called in a bunch, in an arbitrary order by `Entity`'s methods `encode` and `decode(Map)` and 2) should be made available to be called separately by specifying a trait type, or better, by a string parameter like `decode("component-n", Map)`.

It is not possible to use methods with the same name as they will be lost due to shadowing or overriding. I can think of a solution, where all the methods are stored in a `Map[String, Map[String, String] => Unit]` for decode and `Map[String, () => Map[String, String]]` for encode in *every* entity. This would work - the by-name as well as a bunch call would certainly be available. However, this will result in storing the same information in every entity which is unacceptable.

It is also possible to store these maps in a companion object so that it is not duplicated anywhere and call the object's `encode` and `decode` method with an extra parameter denoting a particular instance of the entity.

The requirement may seem strange, but it is necessary because of the required speed and modularity. All of these solutions are clumsy and i think there is a better and idiomatic solution in Scala, or maybe I am missing some important architectural pattern here. So is there any simpler and more idiomatic approach than the one with the companion object?

**EDIT:** I think that aggregation instead of inheritance could probably resolve these problems but at a cost of not being able to call methods directly on an entity.

**UPDATE:** Exploring the pretty promising way proposed by Rex Kerr, I have stumbled upon something that hinders. Here is the test case:

```
trait Component {
  def encode: Map[String, String]
  def decode(m: Map[String, String]) 
}

abstract class Entity extends Component // so as to enforce the two methods

trait ComponentA extends Component {
  var a = 10
  def encode: Map[String, String] = Map("a" -> a.toString)
  def decode(m: Map[String, String]) {
    println("ComponentA: decode " + m)
    m.get("a").collect{case aa => a = aa.toInt}
  }
}

trait ComponentB extends ComponentA {
  var b = 100
  override def encode: Map[String, String] = super.encode + ("b" -> b.toString)
  override def decode (m: Map[String, String]) {
    println("ComponentB: decoding " + m)
    super.decode(m)
    m.get("b").foreach{bb => b = bb.toInt}
  } 
}

trait ComponentC extends Component {
  var c = "hey!"
  def encode: Map[String, String] = Map("c" -> c)
  def decode(m: Map[String, String]) {
    println("ComponentC: decode " + m)
    m.get("c").collect{case cc => c = cc}
  }
}

trait ComponentD extends ComponentB with ComponentC {
  var d = 11.6f
  override def encode: Map[String, String] = super.encode + ("d" -> d.toString)
  override def decode(m: Map[String, String]) {
    println("ComponentD: decode " + m)
    super.decode(m)
    m.get("d").collect{case dd => d = dd.toFloat}
  }
}
```

and finally

```
class EntityA extends ComponentA with ComponentB with ComponentC with ComponentD
```

so that

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ea = new EntityA
    val map = Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> "3", "c" -> "what?", "d" -> "11.24")
    println("BEFORE: " + ea.encode)
    ea.decode(map)
    println("AFTER: " + ea.encode)
  }
}
```

which gives:

```
BEFORE: Map(c -> hey!, d -> 11.6)
ComponentD: decode Map(a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> what?, d -> 11.24)
ComponentC: decode Map(a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> what?, d -> 11.24)
AFTER: Map(c -> what?, d -> 11.24)
```

The A and B components are not influenced, being cut-off by the inheritance resolution. So this approach is only applicable in certain hierarchy cases. In this case we see that the `ComponentD` has shadowed everything else. Any comments are welcomed.

**UPDATE 2:** I place the comment that answers this problem here, for better reference: "Scala linearizes all the traits. There should be a supertrait of everything which will terminate the chain. In your case, that means that `C` and `A` should still call `super`, and `Component` should be the one to terminate the chain with a no-op." – *Rex Kerr*

Comment: Why don't you use some sort of generic solution to implement the encoding, rather than hand-code all the encode methods yourself?

Comment: @RobinGreen can you show an example of such a solution? I am almost sure that it involves much reflection or much-much more additional casting (although, automatic) than the hand-made one. There is a plenty of good generic solutions, but they all cost speed. Also I am not sure if this will help me with my main goal in this task - to create a slim solution for handling the individual encoding-decoding. Although if you know of any interesting examples, please share, maybe I have missed them and they will suit?

Comment: Won't you run into a bunch of problems when mixing two different Components which both define a var with the same name e.g. `trait A extends Component { var name = "" }` and `trait B extends Component { var name = "" }`? I do not understand why you don't use the more idiomatic Cake Pattern. That way name clashes will be rarer, and more easily avoided yes?

Comment: @EmilH Name clashes are not a problem in this particular case. The Cake pattern (as far as I understand it) is good for modularization and abstraction, but I do not understand how would it help to acheive the functionality that I have described, like calling the method `entity.encode("spatial")` or `entity.encode[Spatial]()` or alike to get a `Map` of values that relates to the trait `Spatial`. I might be unqualified in this topic - if you can explain me how do I acheive this with the Cake pattern, or give me a link where I can read about that, I would be happy.

Comment: Ok if name clashes is a non-issue then Cake pattern wouldn't be necessary I suppose (reading my comment I see it's worded a bit strongly, my bad =)). To do the encoding part you could have all your components have a dependency on a trait (for instance named `EncoderMapper`) containing a map between the string (e.g. "spatial") and a function defining how that encoding should be done. Then each Component could add an entry to that map. When encoding is called on the Entity it could simply look up the right encoder to do the work.

Comment: @EmilH All is fine, we all always wish best to share the knowledge in the name of wisdom and understanding :))) I think that the `EncoderMapper` is almost the same as the first approach that I have suggested - it would load each instance with a map (identical for instances of one entity type) of methods? Or am I not quite right here? I am not a Scala pro, so I have more questions than anything else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travis had an essentially correct answer; not sure why he deleted it.  But, anyway, you can do this without too much grief as long as you're willing to make your encoding method take an extra parameter, and that when you decode you're happy to just set mutable variables, not create a new object.  (Complex trait-stacking effectively-at-runtime ranges from difficult to impossible.)

The basic observation is that when you chain traits together, it defines a hierarchy of superclass calls.  If each of these calls takes care of the data in that trait, you'd be set, as long as you can find a way to get all that data back.  So

```
trait T {
  def encodeMe(s: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = Seq()
  def encode = encodeMe(Seq())
}
trait A extends T {
  override def encodeMe(s: Seq[String]) = super.encodeMe(s) :+ "A"
}
trait B extends T {
  override def encodeMe(s: Seq[String]) = super.encodeMe(s) :+ "B"
}
```

Does it work?

```
scala> val a = new A with B
a: java.lang.Object with A with B = $anon$1@41a92be6

scala> a.encode
res8: Seq[String] = List(A, B)

scala> val b = new B with A
b: java.lang.Object with B with A = $anon$1@3774acff

scala> b.encode
res9: Seq[String] = List(B, A)
```

Indeed!  Not only does it work, but you get the order for free.

Now we need a way to set variables based on this encoding.  Here, we follow the same pattern--we take some input and just go up the super chain with it.  If you have very many traits stacked on, you may want to pre-parse text into a map or filter out those parts applicable to the current trait.  If not, just pass on everything to super, and then set yourself after it.

```
trait T {
  var t = 0
  def decode(m: Map[String,Int]) { m.get("t").foreach{ ti => t = ti } }
}
trait C extends T {
  var c = 1
  override def decode(m: Map[String,Int]) { 
    super.decode(m); m.get("c").foreach{ ci => c = ci }
  }
}
trait D extends T {
  var d = 1
  override def decode(m: Map[String,Int]) {
    super.decode(m); m.get("d").foreach{ di => d = di }
  }
}
```

And this too works just like one would hope:

```
scala> val c = new C with D
c: java.lang.Object with C with D = $anon$1@549f9afb

scala> val d = new D with C
d: java.lang.Object with D with C = $anon$1@548ea21d

scala> c.decode(Map("c"->4,"d"->2,"t"->5))

scala> "%d %d %d".format(c.t,c.c,c.d)
res1: String = 5 4 2
```

Comment: I deleted the answer because the whole `abstract override` business wasn't actually doing anything in this case (what I get for answering questions first thing in the morning). Yours is better, anyway.

Comment: An interesting approach! I have never thought of that way... really it gives a quite neat and comparatively cheap way to do this. But to expand the theory - how do you think, what would happen in a case of a non-linear parentship hierarchy? For example, what if there is a trait which has another trait as it's parent? This is an interesting case indeed, to see where I can't get what I need with this inheritance model (I think). Let us explore further, please see the update to the original question.

Comment: @noncom - Scala _linearizes_ all the traits.  There should be a supertrait of everything which will terminate the chain.  In your case, that means that C and A should still call super, and `Component` should be the one to terminate the chain with a no-op.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the explanation. That amounts to a complete solution! I will try it out in a real application soon.